# Check Formatting of a String

Tags: c#, string, format

This has probably been answered somewhere before but since there are millions of unrelated posts about string formatting.

Take the following string:

> 24:Something(true;false;true)[0,1,0]

I want to be able to do two things in this case. I need to check whether or not all the following conditions are true:

- <del>There is only one :</del> Achieved using Split() which I needed to use anyway to separate the two parts.
- <del>The integer before the : is a 1-3 digit int</del> Simple int.parse logic
- The () exists, and that the "Something", in this case any string less than 10 characters, is there
- The [] exists and has at least 1 integer in it. Also, make sure the elements in the [] are integers separated by ,

How can I best do this?
EDIT: I have crossed out what I've achieved so far.

Comment: In order to check everything after the : I now have the two split into strings. The entire part after the : is stored in a string which will make that easier to check.

Comment: And what do you want to be in ()? true/false statemets separated by ","?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A regular expression is the quickest way. Depending on the complexity it may also be the most computationally expensive.

This seems to do what you need (I'm not that good so there might be better ways to do this):

`^\d{1,3}:\w{1,9}\((true|false)(;true|;false)*\)\[\d(,[\d])*\]$`

**Explanation**

`\d{1,3}`
1 to 3 digits

`:`
followed by a colon

`\w{1,9}`
followed by a 1-9 character **alpha-numeric** string,

`\((true|false)(;true|;false)*\)`
followed by parenthesis containing "true" or "false" followed by any number of ";true" or ";false",

`\[\d(,[\d])*\]`
followed by another set of parenthesis containing a digit, followed by any number of comma+digit.

The ^ and $ at the beginning and end of the string indicate the start and end of the string which is important since we're trying to verify the entire string matches the format.

**Code Sample**

```
var input = "24:Something(true;false;true)[0,1,0]";

var regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"^\d{1,3}:.{1,9}\(.*\)\[\d(,[\d])*\]$");
bool isFormattedCorrectly = regex.IsMatch(input);
```

Credit @ Ian Nelson

Comment: Hi, please see the edits I have put in and help me understand what your regex expression says - I am quite new to them.

Comment: Just added a couple of ` - otherwise the *s in the expression were being used as formatting indicators...

Comment: I... am going to go read up on regex's :) Hopefully I'll be able to understand what you've got there once I have. By the way, does anyone else think this would work properly? I'll test it in a min here..

Comment: Nice explanation. Let me test this out and I'll get back to you in a second.

Comment: @PaoloTedesco lol wrong person. Thanks for the formatting edit.

Comment: @ChristianStewart I've tested it using the regex tester, but humans make mistakes :)

Comment: You get the magic cookie for the awesome explanation. Thanks so much for the help guys!

Comment: I have one more thing to ask - I need it to be not only true/false in the parentisies but also any integer. I still don't know enough about RegEx (though I am learning) to do this on my own - can anyone lend a hand?

Comment: @ChristianStewart \d matches 1 digit. When you say "integer" do you mean any length of integer? (this is where being absolutely specific, with sample data to match against) comes in handy

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3955/discussion-between-christian-stewart-and-daryl-teo)

Answer (score 2):

This is one of those cases where your only sensible option is to use a Regular Expression.

My hasty attempt is something like:

```
var input = "24:Something(true;false;true)[0,1,0]";

var regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"^\d{1,3}:.{1,9}\(.*\)\[\d(,[\d])*\]$");

System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(regex.IsMatch(input));
```

[This online RegEx tester should help refine the expression.](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx)

Comment: I'm quite new to Regex's, please help me by being more specific. Thanks!

Comment: Very nice answer. Thank you. I am accepting the other one becuase it has the explanation, but if I could accept two I would accept yours too.

Comment: @Ian, your regex isn't correct, it accepts for example string: "24:Som:thing(true;false;true)[0,1,0]" which has two ":"

Comment: @Lucasus Ah, true, thanks. I was mentally processing the rules in serial, so I was matching the "Something" section as "any string less than 10 characters", and had forgotten the rule about only one colon. The perils of Regexes!

Answer (score 1):

I think, the best way is to use regular expressions like this:

```
string s = "24:Something(true;false;true)[0,1,0]";
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"^\d{1,3}:[a-zA-z]{1,10}\((true|false)(;true|;false)*\)\[\d(,\d)*\]$");

if (pattern.IsMatch(s))
{
   // s is valid
}
```

If you want anything inside (), you can use following regex:

```
@"^\d{1,3}:[a-zA-z]{1,10}\([^:\(]*\)\[\d(,\d)*\]$"
```